# how to pass a value to every view with django middleware

Tags: django, django-views, django-middleware

I have a middleware function that overrides process view.

I want to pass a variable to every view.  Is the best place to do this in the request, args or kwargs parameter to view_func?

I tried this with no luck:

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        view_kwargs['value'] = 'my value'

        response = view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)


        return response
```

How can I pass a value to every view with middleware?

Comment: If a user has not set a setting, I want to popup a message to them.  I will base this off of a session variable.  I figured if the session variable was true, I would pass a variable to the view to pass to the template.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bars on your comment, you probably want to use a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) to get your variable into the template context.

**Edit for example**

It's pretty trivial, but here you go:

```
def my_context_processor(request):
    if request.session['my_variable']:
        return {'foo': 'bar'}
```

then you add `myapp.mymodule.my_context_processor` to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py, and make sure you use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) shortcut in the view to render your template.

Comment: should I still be using the middleware override in conjunction with the context processor?

Comment: No, why would you need to? You have access to the request, and therefore the session, directly in the context processor, so all the logic can go there.

Comment: can you show an example? I can't find any example of the request context being able to pass variable to a template based on conditional logic.  Thanks a million.